# Ruby on Rails Active Record create: No Method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Doing my first steps with Ruby on Rails, I am trying to create my database model with active records. 
For now, I have done this:

```
rails generate model seminar title 
rails generate model student firstname lastname
```

Than I ran rake db:migrate and edited the .rb files like this:

```
class Seminar < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :seminar
end
```

After that, I created a new Seminar-Object in rails console:

```
 seminar = Seminar.create(title: 'The first')
```

Now I want to create a new Student-Object:

```
seminar.students.create(firstname: 'Peter', lastname: 'Pan')
```

And at this point, I get the following error:

```
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
NoMethodError: undefined method `val' for #<Arel::Nodes::BindParam:0x000000057b28c0>
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:572:in `block (2 levels) in where_values_hash'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:568:in `fetch'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:568:in `block in where_values_hash'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:566:in `map'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:566:in `where_values_hash'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:579:in `scope_for_create'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:503:in `create_scope'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:168:in `initialize_attributes'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:248:in `block in build_record'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:282:in `initialize'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:131:in `build_association'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:247:in `build_record'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:489:in `block in _create_record'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:173:in `block in transaction'
... 11 levels...
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/izb/Development/railstests/modeltest/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/izb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /home/izb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/izb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.0 :003 >
```

And I can't figure out the problem.

Also I wonder if I need to edit both classes (has_many / belongs_to) or if this is redundant.

Comment: you need another migration for the foreign key

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28297348/687142 sontya's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be seminar_id as foreign key in Student table
So run command ->

`rails g migration add_seminar_id_to_students seminar_id:integer`

then do

`rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I thought the respective field (seminar_id) would be added automatically when I edit the classes with belongs_to  / has_many;)

Answer (score 1):

i assume you have the following:-

1. Two models..`seminar.rb` and `student.rb`
2. Two tables ..`seminars` and `students`(with `seminar_id` column) with migrations

because when you say `seminars.students.create()`...you are **linking two tables** ..the later by foreign_key `seminar_id` in `students` table....

Comment: Thats right, When I look to my database, I see that rails created these two tables, although there are no foreign keys in them.